# Best way to turn RaspberryPi become Dashboard

Tags: raspberry-pi, dashboard

I am new with this Pi device and just got an Pi 3 Model B. I would like to make a small project with it by turning it to become a dashboard to display some data which get from the server. To do this I have a server running on my laptop which will provide the data. Then I create an html page to draw the dashboard, I draw using highcharts tool. Finally I display the result on the Pi (connected with a monitor using HDMI cabel) by just using its web browser and access to the html page and then the result will be displayed on the monitor.

But what I realise at the end is that I just use the web browser of the Raspberry Pi to display the dashboard and this was not dealing much with the programming of the Raspberry Pi. Therefore I would like to ask that is there any other ways to program with the Pi so that it can connect with the server, get the result and then display the result in a chart as a dashboard. This sound better than my solution as using the Pi as a programming tool instead of displaying tool.

Thank you so much

Comment: What statistics are you wanting to get from your server? What operating system is the server running?

Comment: Hi, I test using Wildfly server, running under windows 7. The server will provide just number data, ex: 10, 15, 60... and I would like to make it display on the Pi as a dashboard (with column maybe), and this dashboard will be updated each x time interval